# How to start master page from bottom of status bar in ios?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am using MasterDetailPage in xamarin forms. In android the Master page starts below the status bar when I click at hamburger icon, but in ios it is starting at top from where status bar  starts. I want to start the master page below the status bar in ios also when user click on master icon. How can I set the master page so that it can visible below the status bar in ios? I have attached an image to show how I want it in ios.

[image]

Comment: Ok,not understand the image.You means that show item start from where status bar starts in IOS.Suggest that show two image with ios and android.

Comment: no, like in image you can see below the status bar there is a shadow. I want this same shadow in ios also. but in ios the master page of master detail page starts from the top where status bar is. so not able to start master page below status bar in ios and also not able to add shadow below the status bar. Don't want to overlap master page over status bar. Master page should start from the navigation bar

Comment: You cannot do this with a master detail page